# In Perl, I need to read a .conf file that contains condition like $a>$b based on the result of the condition i have to execute either if or else block

Tags: perl

The content of `condition.conf`:

```
condition1=$a>$b
```

Example Perl code:

```
$cnd_ConfFile = $ARGV[0];
open(CONDITIONS, '<', $cndConfFile);

$cndCount=0;
while ( <CONDITIONS> ) {
        chomp; # no newline
        s/#.*//; # no comments
        s/^\s+//; # no leading white
        s/\s+$//; # no trailing white
        next unless length;
        ($var, $value) = split(/\s*=\s*/, $_, 2);
        $cndOnCounterValues[$cndCount++]=$value;
}

close CONDITIONS;

$cond = $cndOnCounterValues[0];
print "\n$cond\n";

$a=3;
$b=5;

if($cond){
  print "a is greater then b";
}
else
{
  print "b is greater then a";
}
```

The above code always gives the output "`a is greater then b`".

Regardless of the values of `$a` and `$b`.

Comment: Please format your question so others don't have a hard time reading it.

Comment: ... and please provide a short example of a file containing condidtions.

Comment: Note that the missing * in the "no comments" and "split" regexes are stripped due to no formatting.

Comment: Programming may not be for you if you have difficulty conceptually distinguishing code from data.

Comment: We all had to start somewhere :)

Comment: @Inshalla Take a look at the OP's posting history: Not much interest in actual learning, focused on getting quick answers that solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @kishore Recommendations: Don't roll your own config file parse, use on from CPAN. Think very hard about what you are trying to do. There is very little justification for storing executable snippets in config files. Explain what you are trying to at a higher level.

Comment: I love that: poster dumps question and runs for it. This guy has asked 7 questions, but has never answered, never voted, never edited a question and never accepted an answer.

Comment: I did some basic formatting, but oh dear god this code is horrible...

Comment: and thanks to your efforts, we can now see it in all its glory.

Answer (score 2):

Here i a quick example that seems to satisfy your problem.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @cond;
{
  while( <> ){
    chomp;
    next unless length;
    next if m' ^ \s* \# 'x;

    next unless m' (\w+) \s* = \s* (.*?) \s* $'x;
    push @cond, [$1,$2];
  }
}
my($a,$b);

$a=3;
$b=5;

for my $elem ( @cond ){
  my($name,$cond) = @$elem;

  if( eval $cond ){
    print "$name is true, because $cond matches "
  }else{
    print "$name is false, because $cond doesn't match "
  }
  print '(', eval("qq{$cond}"), ")\n";
}
```

```
echo 'condition1=$a>$b
condition2=$a<$b' | perl test.pl
```

```
condition1 is false, because $a>$b doesn't match (3>5)
condition2 is true, because $a<$b matches (3<5)
```

Comment: If you wanted to make it safer you would match `(~~|[<>=]+)` instead of `(.*?)`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to eval the $a>$b expression that literally appears in your config file. To do that replace:

```
if ($cond) {
```

with:

```
if (eval $cond) {
```

That should to the trick.

Disclaimer: don't do this unless you know what you are doing (see comments).

Comment: The fundamental question, always, concerns the difference between the quick answer to OP's misguided question versus good programming practice. Your answer falls on the wrong side of that comparison.

Comment: You are being too critical. It is not wrong to use eval like that if it's not going to be used as real code; it seems to me that the OP is simply messing around.

Comment: @Inshalla Maybe ... maybe not. I am leaving the comment but got rid of my down vote.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür: Leave it. I can see that you have made a good point.

Comment: @Inshalla: Tell you what for having the right answer, I'll give you my up, IF you put caveats in place.

Comment: Rather than meta-discussion, let's state it straight: if you use eval, you're executing code from the config file.  If the person who writes the config file is not supposed to have code execution rights, this is a Bad Thing.  If you want to do it differently you would have to parse any expressions like this in your config file, and that's a lot harder than using 'eval'.  And if you write the config file and the code yourself, then you have absolutely nothing to worry about.

Comment: I would probably add a disclaimer that this shouldn't be used in production code.